# What is the difference between react framework & Backed framewaork

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With react-router I can use the Link element to create links that are natively handled by react router.

I see internally it calls this.context.transitionTo(...).

I want to do a navigation, but not from a link, from a dropdown selection for example. How can I do this in code? What is this.context?

I saw the Navigation mixin, but can I do this without mixins?

Comment: You show read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so firstly, `ReactJS` & `React-Native` are for two different areas, `ReactJS` is primarily for web applications like websites. `React-Native` is mostly mobile development for as a `Native` hybrid solution to create applications for iOS, Android & Windows.

I would recommend picking one and learning it thoroughly, if you want a website go for `ReactJS`, if you want mobile apps then go for `React-Native`. When you're searching for help, try not to confuse the two, here's a few guides.

`React-Native` Guides:

1. http://www.reactnativeexpress.com/
2. https://hackr.io/tutorials/learn-react-native
3. https://rationalappdev.com/movie-tickets-booking-app-with-react-native/

`ReactJS` Guides:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A&t=200s
2. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html
3. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/